# Geoserver filter point

Tags: geoserver, wfs, filter

I'm trying to make a filter function that I add to an URL.
I managed to make it work for polygon, but I'm struggling with filter function for point type.

Currently I am trying to use something like this:

```
<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc/" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><Contains><PropertyName>geometry</PropertyName><gml:Point><gml:coordinates>520757.13197114784 120868.02826434454 </gml:coordinates></gml:Point></Contains></Filter>
```

I keep getting `<ows:ExceptionText>java.util.NoSuchElementException</ows:ExceptionText>`, I narrowed my problem to filter, since I get correct response without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was way too simple. Problem was that I was not defining coordinates separators...

Correct filter function would be:

```
<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc/" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><Contains><PropertyName>geometry</PropertyName><gml:Point><gml:coordinates decimal="." cs=" " ts="_">520757.13197114784 120868.02826434454 </gml:coordinates></gml:Point></Contains></Filter>
```